# Oracle Hibernate : Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Ok, this question has already been asked a million times but none of the answers I found on the site was for a simple example.

I have a simple stored procedure with a parameter in and parameter out (just for the test), I do not need cursor for my final procedure.

```
Procedure testout (
                  a_s_out IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                  --
                  a_s_in IN VARCHAR2
                  )
IS
BEGIN
  a_s_out := 'Votre demande de creation ' || a_s_in || ' est réussi.'; 
END testout;
```

And the java code:

```
@Service
public class TablesDaoImpl implements ITablesDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    final static String PRC_TESTOUT = "PCK_TOOLS.testout";

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TablesDaoImpl.class.getName());


    @Override
    public String createTable(final String newTabId) {
        ProcedureCall call = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createStoredProcedureCall(PRC_TESTOUT);
        ParameterRegistration<String> p1 = call.registerParameter("a_s_out", String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);
        ParameterRegistration<String> p2 = call.registerParameter("a_s_in", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        p1.bindValue("");
        p2.bindValue(newTabId);

        final ProcedureOutputs po = call.getOutputs();

        final String str = po.getOutputParameterValue(p1);

        log.info("Sortie : " + str);

        return null;
    }


}
```

But i got an SQL error on this line `final String str = po.getOutputParameterValue(p1);` :

```
2017-03-24 17:26:59,129 [HJwlMLxG DEV] WARN  [SqlExceptionHelper] : SQL Error: 17090, SQLState: 99999
2017-03-24 17:26:59,129 [HJwlMLxG DEV] ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] : opération interdite: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!
2017-03-24 17:26:59,130 [HJwlMLxG DEV] ERROR [LoggingHandlerExceptionResolver] : Spring MVC Exception for [GET /api/tables/tables/creerTable] : Unable to extract OUT/INOUT parameter value
class org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:Unable to extract OUT/INOUT parameter value
```

Why ?  I tried with OUT parameter it's the same failure...

Comment: From which library are `ProcedureCall` and `ParameterRegistration`? Google does not seem to be able to find Javadoc for them.  Show your imports and tell us where you got the library.

Comment: Hi, this are my imports :

`import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;`
`import org.apache.log4j.layout.Log4j1XmlLayout;`
`import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;`
`import org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterRegistration;`
`import org.hibernate.procedure.ProcedureCall;`
`import org.hibernate.procedure.ProcedureOutputs;`
`import org.hibernate.result.ResultSetOutput;`
`import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;`
`import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;`

hibernate-validator 4.1.0 and hibernate-core 5.0.9; spring 4.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Well, i don't kwo why, but it works if i do like this :

```
ParameterRegistration<String> p1 = call.registerParameter(0, String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);
ParameterRegistration<String> p2 = call.registerParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

p1.bindValue("");
p2.bindValue(newTabId);

final ProcedureOutputs po = call.getOutputs();
final String str = po.getOutputParameterValue(p1);
log.info("Sortie : " + str);
```

Comment: Seems that createStoredProcedureCall can't work with Oracle IN OUT parameters